# Streaming audio/video to iPhone other than http server

Tags: iphone, audio, video, video-streaming, audio-streaming

I find most of streaming audio discussions are about the streaming media from http server, e.g. AudioStreamer from cocoa with love or `MPMoviePlayerController`. They both init with `NSURL`. But my case is other than that. I use SMB to access the media files on some window shared server. The media content is got with SMB message (thru socket) and is accumulated in memory （`NSMutableData`）

So is there a way to play them (those `NSMutableData`) before download is finished ?

Update, so for streaming audio I understand I need audio queue service.

What about stream video other than http? I think it is doable because there is a free app called TIOD which does not only stream audio but also video from SMB server.

BTW, I never expect others to do work for me. I check all the document I can find and can't find a way to do it (for video). I had thought, well, that may mean it can't be done. But then I find TIOD can do that. That's why I raised the quesion in the first place to see if other has experiences for it.

Answer (score 0):

Yea you can stream that as well, its the same thing as getting the data from an NSURL... if you look at audio streaming example by matt gallagher [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html) you see that he is getting data from some URL, but ultimatly when he calls the parse function he is giving it bytes of data, same things should apply for your situation, with the data you get you should be able to call the parse function and have the Audio Player stream your audio file..

Comment: I was referring to that article as well. But I do not have knowledge of Audio File Stream Services and I am looking for some quick solution like AVAudioPlayer, which accept a NSData and play it out. But AVAudioPlayer does not accept partial audio data. So do you mean there is no way to bypass Audio File Stream Services (by bypass I mean learning it) ?

Comment: Nope, if u wanna stream there is no quick solution , you gonna have to adapt the code to ur needs

Comment: OK. So what about streaming video in my case? MPMoviePlayerViewController also accept NSURL too.

Comment: if you have an accesable URL to your movie  i would say you could use MPMoviePlayer to play it, you wont be able to send the data and stream it just like that tho

Comment: There is free app called TIOD, it does not only stream audio but also video from SMB server.

Comment: ok?...you should look into it yourself, dont expect people to do work for you here